# Akka stream stays idle instead of throwing exception

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am new to Akka/Scala and am trying to debug the code below. When the `resultSetParser` has an exception, it does not throw it. Instead the service that uses this code just sits idle forever.

How can I make my service throw the exception rather than just waiting forever on the stream? Is there something like a `watchException()` function in Akka that I could call right after `watchTermination()` to make it throw the exception it sees when processing a stream?

```
val chunkSource: Source[ChunkStreamPart, NotUsed] =
  Source
    .fromIterator(() => resultSetParser(resultSet) map ChunkStreamPart.apply)
    .watchTermination()((mat : NotUsed, fut : Future[Done]) => {
      watchTermination(fut)
      mat
    })
val chunkEntity = Chunked(ContentTypes.`application/json`, chunkSource)
```

Comment: can you provide the signatures of `resultSetParser` and `watchTermination` for clarification?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`recover`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/stream/stream-error.html#recover)?

For example (not tested):

```
Source
    .fromIterator(() => resultSetParser(resultSet) map ChunkStreamPart.apply)
    .recover{
        case _: RuntimeException => ??? /* Return ChunkStreamPart here */
    }
```